# Force index not working in Aurora MySQL 8

Tags: query-performance, index-tuning, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora, aurora

I have recently upgraded to `Aurora MySQL engine version 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.05.2` from Aurora MySQL 5.7. I see huge performance issue after upgrading. Recently I found that I have queries whose indexes are being ignored and doing full table scan

My `orders` table row count is `20 million`

Here is the query

```
select * 
from `orders` 
FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
where `orders`.`id` in (/* almost 64000 comma separated ids which are primary keys */)
```

When I do `EXPLAIN` on this it says that it is doing full table scan with `type = ALL

```
show create table orders
```

show this

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ... other columns,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24105494 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I checked on some blog and put `optimizer_switch` to `index_condition_pushdown=on` in parameter groups but it doesn't work

How can I force the index it so that query is fast

Comment: Why don't you save the list of ids on a temporary table and join with orders ?

Comment: Join will degrade performance. No?

Comment: I can try that approach. But why force index is not working? Any idea?

Comment: On the contrary , join will increase performance. By the way forcing an index doesn't mean the optimizer will use it if it thinks it is better to use a table scan, which is your case. Keep in mind that using in `id in(1,2,3,4,....)` is interpreted as `id =1 or id =2 or id=3 or id=4 ....` and it is known that or is a performance killer

Comment: I do not know about Aurora but `MySQL` probably in a future release will remove force/use index

Comment: I tried temporary tables, and it further reduces the performance